# VS2012 ASP.NET website running System.Exception

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I have a problem with my VS2012 Ultimate RC.

When I click on start debugging for my website application built in ASP.NET 4.5 web forms, the website builds, no error, but I get an error message "System.Exception" the page don't run in the browser.

If I click on Ctrl+F5 (Debug=false) I get the page in the browser, and it works perfectly.

The system exception i get is from the VS, I don't have any output on the webpage, I don't even come to the point that a webpage shows in the browser
Its not from the code! the code is great, i guess its a general error in the VS2012

here is a picture of what i get:[image]

Comment: Don't use a Release Candidate.

Comment: It used to work before!!

Comment: @Ondrej Tucny
Do you mean I musn't use the VS2012 RC??
What do you suggest?

Comment: It makes no sense to use an RC when a RTM is available for *months* already. First, get up-to-date tools and then try again.